# How to cache the rss feed?

Tags: zend-framework, caching, rss

I want to cache the rss feed from our index page in case my website get slows down..

Comment: Well there's Zend Cache which helps with caching. Do you have a specific problem implementing caching?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/athom09/2010/06/04/caching-rss-feeds-zend-framework

one caveat though. There is no explanation on how to pass the $config to getNews($config)
very time I try to pass it as:

//in my controller

$this->config = new Zend_Config(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/feeds_config.xml');

$this->view->articles = $this->feed->getNews($config);

the app crashes with 500 internal server error.
If you know the resolution - let me know